# How can I rewrite this URL using .htaccess

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

How can I rewrite this URL

> `http://staging.felgenexklusiv.de/?felge=asa-gt1`

to be displayed like this?

> `http://staging.felgenexklusiv.de/felge/asa-gt1`

This is my existing .htaccess file:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just before `</IfModule>` insert these lines:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(?:index\.php|)\?(felge)=([^\s&]*) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ %1/%2? [NC,L,R]

RewriteRule ^(felge)/(.*)/?$ /?$1=$2 [NC,L,QSA]
```

Comment: Display the page as I wanted, but does a bad redirect. Ends up in 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS)! What is wrong?

Comment: Still fails, but now redirects me to the base!

Comment: I think that was due to your existing rules. I made another edit that should work fine with your existing rules. Please try and let me know.

Answer (score 1):

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
 RewriteEngine On
 RewriteBase /
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
 RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
 RewriteRule ^/([a-zA-Z]+)/([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+)?/?(.*)$ index.php?partie=$1&name=$2&%{QUERY_STRING} [L,QSA]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Thanks! I updated my Question. Is anything affected by your solution?